# Handling FileNotFoundException in a different file

Tags: java, file, class

It's been a while since I've used Java so I feel silly that this is confusing me, but I have a class 'FileProcessor' in a 'FileProcessor.java' file. I'm trying to use it in my 'Driver.java' file but I keep getting this error:

`error: unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown`

I'm a little confused by the whole exceptions thing in Java and I thought I handled it in my FileProcessor.java file but I don't know.

FileProcessor.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class FileProcessor{
   /**
     * Reads one line from file
     * @param arg A file
     * @return The line that is read
     */
   public String readLineFromFile(File f) throws FileNotFoundException,
                                                IOException{
      BufferedReader br = null;
      String line;
      try{
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
         line = br.readLine();

         return line;
      }
      catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.err.println("Read method failed");
         throw new IOException();
      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException e1){
         e1.getMessage();
         System.err.println("File is not found");
         throw new FileNotFoundException();
      }

   }

}
```

Driver.java

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Driver{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      File inFile = null;
      if (0 < args.length){
         inFile = new File(args[0]);
      }
      else{
         System.err.println("No input file found");
         System.exit(0);
      }
      FileProcessor fileProcessor = new FileProcessor();
      String lineRead;
      try{
         lineRead = fileProcessor.readLineFromFile(inFile);
      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException e){
         throw new FileNotFoundException();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why do you catch the exception(s), just to throw a new (completely unrelated, with no helpful information) exception directly afterwards. You should look into some tutorial on exception handling. "If you can't handle it, then don't"

Answer (score 0):

Your `main` throws a new `FileNotFoundException` in the catch block which can't be catched outside of main. Change:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class Driver{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      File inFile = null;
      if (0 < args.length){
         inFile = new File(args[0]);
      }
      else{
         System.err.println("No input file found");
         System.exit(0);
      }
      FileProcessor fileProcessor = new FileProcessor();
      String lineRead;
      try{
         lineRead = fileProcessor.readLineFromFile(inFile);
      }
      catch(FileNotFoundException e){
         System.out.print(e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to do with Exceptions.

1. You catch the Exception and you write your appropriate code needed to handle the Exception, Example logging, setting error message or triggering fail mail, retry with new file name etc. For this you write the catch block along with try.

2.You catch the Exception and you write your appropriate code needed to handle the Exception, Example logging etc but you want future code which calls your method to catch and process the exception again. In this case you will re throw the exception using throw new  and add it in throws. you can even throw new Exception type like

```
catch(NullPointerException e) {
  throw new RecipeNotFoundException("No recipe found");
}
```

3. Delay the handling to future code which calls this method. This is done by writing throws clause. Throws tell method(s) calling a method that there are possibilities an exception can occur here and it is not caught and you need to catch and you wont write catch.

In your code you have caught the code in FileProcessor.readLineFromFile(File) method but you have also added throws clause to the method. So the system thinks there are chances an exception can be re thrown and not caught possible another FileNotFoundException from the catch block.

One more thing after catching the Exception you have re thrown same exception throw new IOException(); and throw new FileNotFoundException(); remove that  too.

If you go through Java documentation on FileNotFoundException and IOException here. docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/… and docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html you will notice FileNotFoundException actually extends IOException so you do not have to actually catch FileNotFoundException.

Comment: So removing the throws clause INSIDE Driver.java gave me the error 'unreported exception IOException', which I fixed with a `catch(IOException e1)` but I don't get why I have to catch them both in my FileProcessor class and the Driver class. If I remove the throws inside FileProcessor.java, I get a 'missing return statement' error

Comment: If you go through Java documentation on FileNotFoundException and IOException here.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html
and
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html

you will notice FileNotFoundException actually extends IOException so you do not have to actually catch FileNotFoundException.

Comment: If you remove the throws inside FileProcessor it gives compilation error because, your method expects a return value of String and you have returned String only when there is no Exception, i.e. try block. Your catch block do not return anything. return some string from catch block or you return some String at the end of the function (i.e outside try and after catch ends )

Answer (score 0):

Throwing a new IO- or FileNotFoundException when you catch them is not a good handling of this exceptions.

```
catch(IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
     System.err.println("Read method failed");
     throw new IOException();
}
```

First, you loose the Exception information (which file can not be found, what exactly happened, ...). Second, it does not really catch them if you throw it again, so you have to catch them again one frame above.

So, the simplest possible solution is to delete the throw statement.

```
public class FileProcessor{
   public String readLineFromFile(File f) 
       // this can be deleted if you catch the exceptions 
       // in here (and do not rethrow them)
       // throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
   {
      BufferedReader br = null;
      try {
         br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));
         return br.readLine();
      } catch(IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         // throw new IOException();
      }
      // this can be deleted because FileNotFoundException is a
      // subclass of IOException and is caught above
      // catch(FileNotFoundException e1){
      //   e1.getMessage();
      //   System.err.println("File is not found");
      //   throw new FileNotFoundException();
      // }

      // and after all, you should close the BufferedReader 
      // or use the "try-with-resources"
      finally {
         if(br != null) { br.close(); }
      }
   }
}
```